# Check if this pointer was accessed in an instance method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to detect if the `this` pointer was accessed in a dot net instance method. Could be a call to an instance method, access to a member variable etc.

Currently digging into Reflection: `MethodBase.GetMethodBody` if I can figure it out from the IL.

Comment: Where else could a `this` pointer be accessed from? Can you give us a couple of examples that would produce different results for your check?

Comment: You're dealing with analyzing use of code during runtime, which is hairy to begin with. Could you frame the larger problem here? There may be alternative solutions

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis It's not a question of where else it would be accessed, but whether it's unused or actually used.  `this` is a parameter to the method, (more or less) like any other.  It'd be just like checking if any other parameter to the method was unused.

Comment: I can see the reasoning... A method that doesn't use the `this` can be made `static` for example. Yes, you can surely find it from the `MethodBase.GetMethodBody`. Using `Mono.Reflector` you can look for the `OpCodes.Ldarg_0`

Comment: @xanatos which would be a good reason to look into compiler or code-analysis extensions, not runtime analysis

Comment: @Aravol It wouldn't be the first time that I write a unit test to test the correctness of some code... Not everyone uses Code Analysis

Comment: @guarav If you use FxCop/CodeAnalysis (that would be the correct place to do this checks), you could write a custom rule, and override the `public override void VisitThis(This thisVariable)` method

Comment: I am playing with IL Injection at runtime to swap methods. When I am swapping methods and the method is static there is no problem because it will not try to access members of the class. But as soon as they are instance methods the swapped method should not try to access any member of the class because now it is running under the context of a different class. so i want to check if that the instance method does not access the this pointer. As long as it is self contained and using locals to do its work it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Mono.Reflection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Reflection/):

```
// using Mono.Reflection;
public static bool ContainsThis(MethodBase method)
{
    if (method.IsStatic)
    {
        return false;
    }

    IList<Instruction> instructions = method.GetInstructions();

    return instructions.Any(x => x.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
}
```

Example of use:

```
public class Foo
{
    private int bar;

    public int Bar
    {
        get { return bar; }
        set { }
    }

    public void CouldBeStatic()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }

    public void UsesThis(int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4, int p5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Bar);
        Console.WriteLine(p5);
    }
}

MethodBase m1 = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("CouldBeStatic");
MethodBase m2 = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("UsesThis");
MethodBase p1 = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").GetGetMethod();
MethodBase p2 = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").GetSetMethod();

bool r1 = ContainsThis(m1); // false
bool r2 = ContainsThis(m2); // true
bool r3 = ContainsThis(p1); // true
bool r4 = ContainsThis(p2); // false
```

Remember the `using Mono.Reflection`.

Ah... How it works... The `this` is a "hidden" parameter, the first one. To load into the stack a parameter in IL code you use `ldarg_#`, where `#` is the parameter number. So in an instance method, `ldarg_0` loads the `this` into the stack.

Comment: You also need to check for the ldarg that takes an integer index.

Comment: What i was looking for. will try some combinations.

Comment: @usr: can you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: You need to check for this opcode as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldarg%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @usr https://github.com/jbevain/mono.reflection/issues/8 Look who opened the bug? :-) There are two additional opcodes. Fortunately, it doesn't seem that the Microsoft C# compiler uses them (preferring the `ldarg.0`).

Comment: Funny. No real-world compiler generates this code I guess. Reflection Emit maybe doesn't either.